# Assert that an `FnOnce` will only ever be used once in a loop

Tags: rust, reference, closures, borrow-checker

I am interfacing with a CLI utility and find myself writing a lot of duplicate code, for matching strings with regex and error handling. I wanted to reduce the mess by creating a reusable function that takes the compiled regex, the text to match against, and a closure that will be used to return a `Result::Err` in the event that any of the matching fails.

I am having trouble with the borrow checker, as per-usual. I want to re-use the same closure for all calls to this "helper" function, but `cargo check` tells me that it can't move the `FnOnce` because it doesn't implement `Copy`. The closure is `FnOnce` and not `Fn` because it takes ownership of `command` (`std::process::Command`) in order to pass it and all of its fields outside of the scope of the function in the event of a failure.

I, as a human, can see that the closure will only ever be called once, but `rustc` cannot.

The first block of code is showing how I am calling `Clazz::captures`, and the second is the static method containing the definition of the "helper".

```rust
        let account = {
            let email: String;
            let active: bool;
            let expires: NaiveDate;

            let fn_bad_output = || CliError::BadOutput(command);

            email = Self::captures(&RE_EMAIL, &stdout, fn_bad_output)?[0].to_owned();
            active = Self::captures(&RE_ACTIVE, &stdout, fn_bad_output)?[0] == "Active";
            expires = {
                let captures = Self::captures(&RE_EMAIL, &stdout, fn_bad_output)?;
                let date = format!("{}-{:02}-{}", captures[1], captures[2], captures[3]);

                NaiveDate::parse_from_str(&date, "%b-%d-%Y")?
            };

            Account {
                email,
                active,
                expires,
            }
        };
```

```rust
    fn captures<'a, F, E>(re: &Regex, text: &'a str, err: F) -> Result<Vec<&'a str>, E>
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> E,
        E: std::error::Error,
    {
        match re.captures(text) {
            Some(captures) => {
                let mut result = Vec::<&str>::new();

                for capture in captures.iter() {
                    let capture = capture.ok_or_else(err)?;
                    result.push(capture.as_str())
                }

                Ok(result)
            }
            None => Err(err()),
        }
    }
```

This is what `cargo check` tells me, including suggestions to restrict the generic bounds which I obviously cannot do.

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `fn_bad_output`
   --> src/cli.rs:109:58
    |
108 |             email = Self::captures(&RE_EMAIL, &stdout, fn_bad_output)?[0].to_owned();
    |                                                        ------------- value moved here
109 |             active = Self::captures(&RE_ACTIVE, &stdout, fn_bad_output)?[0] == "Active";
    |                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
    |
note: closure cannot be moved more than once as it is not `Copy` due to moving the variable `command` out of its environment
   --> src/cli.rs:106:56
    |
106 |             let fn_bad_output = || CliError::BadOutput(command);
    |                                                        ^^^^^^^

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `fn_bad_output`
   --> src/cli.rs:111:67
    |
109 |             active = Self::captures(&RE_ACTIVE, &stdout, fn_bad_output)?[0] == "Active";
    |                                                          ------------- value moved here
110 |             expires = {
111 |                 let captures = Self::captures(&RE_EMAIL, &stdout, fn_bad_output)?;
    |                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
    |
note: closure cannot be moved more than once as it is not `Copy` due to moving the variable `command` out of its environment
   --> src/cli.rs:106:56
    |
106 |             let fn_bad_output = || CliError::BadOutput(command);
    |                                                        ^^^^^^^

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `err`
   --> src/cli.rs:441:54
    |
431 |     fn captures<'a, F, E>(re: &Regex, text: &'a str, err: F) -> Result<Vec<&'a str>, E>
    |                                                      --- move occurs because `err` has type `F`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
441 |                     let capture = capture.ok_or_else(err)?;
    |                                                      ^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
    |
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
433 |         F: FnOnce() -> E + Copy,
    |                          ++++++
```

I have included real source code from my project, if this does not satisfy MCVE I will replace it with a dummy, however I am terrible at coming up with realistic toy examples.

Comment: don't use chain method and try do it with a match but I'm not sure it's will work. Anyway your api is pretty strange I never saw such pattern with any other api

Comment: You could pass a `&mut Option<Fn…>`, and "assert" that it hasn't been used yet by doing `.take().expect(…)`. But really, you want to rethink this.

Comment: This is even more basic than a borrow checker issue. You can't pass the same value to two different closures, regardless of whether the closure will only be called once. Rust values aren't heap allocated like those in Python, so when you send `fn_bad_output` to `email` captures, you no longer have that value. Your options are: 1) send a reference, 2) clone the closure. (You would have the exact same problem in C++, except in C++ the compiler would go ahead and clone it automatically, it's called "copy construction".)

Comment: @user4815162342: Why would he need an Rc/RefCell? A normal `&mut` should do fine…?

Comment: @Caesar Good point, I misread the code as _storing_ `err` and returning it as part of `email` and `active`. `&mut fn_bad_output` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As @user4815162342 said in comments as `BadOutput` keeps `command` the `Copy` trait is not implemented for it. Therefore the `fn_bad_output` value is moved into the first call of the `captures` and cannot be moved into the second one.

The simplified version of your code which still reproduces the error ([link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4ae462aeaa8e7a3634caa3e6872630ef)). I replaced all irrelevant types by `()` and command by `String` for simplicity.

```
struct BadOutput {
    command: String,
}

fn captures<F, E>(ok: bool, err: F) -> Result<(), E>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> E,
{
    if ok {
        Ok(())
    } else {
        Err(err())
    }
}

fn parse(command: String) -> Result<(), BadOutput> {
    let account = {
        let fn_bad_output = || BadOutput{ command };
        let _email = captures(true, fn_bad_output)?;
        let _active = captures(false, fn_bad_output)?;
        Ok(())
    };
    account
}

fn main() {
    parse("test".into());
}
```

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to simplify the error handling by implementing it in a single line of code (`fn_bad_output` implementation). To do this it is not necessary to pass `fn_bad_output` into `captures`. You can capture the error state of `parse` instead and convert it into a `BadOutput` kind of error. This requires one more function to wrap `parse` call and implement error handing in it but it makes overall code simpler.

The code below demonstrates this idea ([link to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ef9a4db7a587dc286928e045e255730d)):

```
struct BadOutput {
    command: String,
}

fn captures(ok: bool) -> Result<(), ()>
{
    if ok {
        Ok(())
    } else {
        Err(())
    }
}

fn parse_bad_output(command: String)  -> Result<(), BadOutput> {
    parse().or_else(|_| Err(BadOutput{ command }))
}

fn parse() -> Result<(), ()> {
    let account = {
        let _email = captures(true)?;
        let _active = captures(false)?;
        Ok(())
    };
    account
}

fn main() {
    parse_bad_output("test".into());
}
```

You may have to return the information about the error into `parse_bad_output`. Then you need to replace second `()` in the return type of the `captures` and `parse` (`Result<(), ()>`) by the specific type and process returned value inside `parse_bad_output`.